# How to set font size for \caption* (but not \caption)

Tags: captions, fontsize, starred-version

I need to change the font size from `\caption*` to `10pt`.However, using `\captionsetup` the `\caption` font size changes as well. How can I solve that?

Comment: Your question was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 8):

The following minimal example changes the starred `\caption` of *all* floats to be different from that of `\caption` using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\caption@@@make`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\captionsetup{font=small}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\caption@@@make}% <cmd>
  {\ifcaption@star}% <search>
    {\ifcaption@star\footnotesize}% <replace>
    {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{figure}\caption{A regular figure caption: \f@size{}pt}\end{figure}
\begin{figure}\caption*{A starred figure caption: \f@size{}pt}\end{figure}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

`\captionsetup` sets the caption font to `\small` in a `12pt` base font, which is equivalent to `10.95pt` (for `\caption`). The patch turns `\caption*`'s font size into `\footnotesize`, which is equivalent to `10pt`.

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used just for this example to reduce the paper size and may not be needed in your application.